# How can I fetch WhatsApp username of a person using python?

Tags: python

I want to know the WhatsApp username of a person he is using on whatsapp using python. Is it possible using the pyWhatKit Module?

Answer (score 2):

Read [`this`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-pywhatkit-module/) article.

> **pywhatkit** is a Python library for sending WhatsApp messages at a certain time

So this is its principal feature, and a few others:

- Send WhatsApp messages.
- Play a YouTube video.
- Perform a Google Search.

So I guess the `WhatsApp API` doesn't return user's data, or at least `pyWhatKit` still can't handle this data.

---

I would suggest to use pure `selenium` instead, like described [`here`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/whatsapp-using-python/).